# Centering a long table latex that doesn't fill width of page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My code is producing the following table [image]

Could anyone tell me a way to make the table smaller and get rid of that big chunk of white space? My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Granger causality wald-test Blockchain Google Trends on Bitcoin weekly price } % title of Table
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \toprule
    Test statistic &  Critical value & p-value & df \\
    \midrule
     13.857480    &    22.362032        &    0.384  &13 \\
    \bottomrule
    $H_0$: ['blockchain'] do not Granger-cause Close Bitcoin Price weekly\\
    Conclusion: fail to reject $H_0$ at 5.00\% significance level\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The last row is the problem. Maybe `\usepackage{multirow}` will help. Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi @Bobyandbob I edited the question and think that what I added should be enough as a MWE, let me know if not. Unfortunately multirow is not helping. I will keep looking for solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic: Please spell the test "Wald test", not "wald-test". The test is named for a real person: a statistician, who first proposed the test, viz., Abraham Wald, 1902-1950. After all, you wouldn't write "granger-cause", would you?

Comment: Try using `\multicolumn` instead of `\multirow`!

Comment: (Sorry, posted my last comment by accident before I had finished it.) Trouble is, your last two lines are too long: All of the text must fit into the first column, therefore it is padded with white space in the rows above. You should use `\multicolumn` instead of `\multirow` for the two lines after `\bottomrule` to use all available horizontal space. 

`\multirow{4}{r}{Your text here}\\\`should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the two longish sentences from the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Wald test of Granger causality from Blockchain Google Trends to Bitcoin weekly price} 

    $H_0$: `blockchain' does not Granger-cause Bitcoin weekly closing price.

    \medskip\centering 
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    Test statistic &  Critical value & $p$-value & df \\
    \midrule
     13.86    &    22.36        &    0.384  & 13 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \medskip\raggedright
    Conclusion: Fail to reject $H_0$ at 5\% significance level.
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```